# How to center align datatables header

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm new to datatables. When I make table header, it's always left align.
How can I set the header to center align?
I've read datatables.net/manual/styling/classes and datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className but still don't know how to implement it.

```
$('.table').DataTable({
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": true,
  "searching": true,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": true,
  "language": {
    "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/i18n/Indonesian.json"
  }
  "columnDefs": {
    {
      className: "dt-head-center"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to use CSS. Can you please make a working snippet so that we can suggest?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might have forgotten after specifying the class, you need to add the following in CSS:

```css
.dt-head-center {text-align: center;}
```

Also, if the class has not been added to the `<th>` of the table, try adding the below CSS for generic stuff:

```css
thead, th {text-align: center;}

/* OR */

.table thead,
.table th {text-align: center;}
```

To make it specific to a particular table, you can give the table an `id="tableID"` and then in the CSS, you can do:

```css
#tableID thead,
#tableID th {text-align: center;}
```

Comment: I found that just making sure the class was on the header was sufficient.  Adding additional css was unnecessary, as it was already in datatables.

Answer (score 19):

OP, you were super close to the solution, just missing the `targets` option in `columnDefs` to assign the `dt-head-center` class to the header you want to style.

```
// apply to columns 1 & 2
targets: [ 0, 1 ]
```

CSS is an option but not necessary.

I like the DataTables suggested method of using the `column.className` option for the styling of cells then apply them using `targets`. https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className This gives us a finer level of control as opposed to a global CSS application.

This will align header and body content individually:

```
columnDefs: [
    // Center align the header content of column 1
   { className: "dt-head-center", targets: [ 0 ] },
   // Center align the body content of columns 2, 3, & 4
   { className: "dt-body-center", targets: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
]
```

or align them both at the same time:

```
columnDefs: [
   // Center align both header and body content of columns 1, 2 & 3
   { className: "dt-center", targets: [ 0, 1, 2 ] }
]
```

Cell class format:

```
dt[-head|-body][-left|-center|-right|-justify|-nowrap]
```

More info on DataTables cell classes: https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes#Cell-classes

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with CSS. Just use your table class as a selector and target every table heading inside that selector, like this:

```
.table th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

by using this style :

```
table.center-all td,th{
    text-align :center;
}
```

I can add the `center-all` class to my table and everything will be aligned to center. like this :

```
<table class="center-all">
    ....
</table
```

In this way I have the option to center the content of some tables without need to apply it to the whole page/site