# How can I align datatable column headers to the left in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt, leftalign

For some reason I cannot have column headers of a datatable properly aligned left:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(mainPanel = 
                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      id = 'dataset',
                      tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
                    )
                  ),sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = ggplot2::diamonds[sample(nrow(ggplot2::diamonds), 1000), ]
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds2,
                  extensions = c('Buttons', 
                                 #'Autofill', 
                                 'ColReorder',
                                 'Responsive',
                                 'Scroller'),
                  style = 'bootstrap',
                  class = 'table-bordered stripe table-condensed',
                  filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list( dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                  buttons = list(list(extend = 'csv',
                                                      buttons = c('csv'),
                                                      exportOptions = list(modifiers = list(page = "current"))
                                                      )
                                                 ),
                                  search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = FALSE),
                                  #autofill = TRUE,
                                  colReorder = TRUE,
                                  deferRender = TRUE,
                                  scrollY = 200,
                                  scroller = TRUE,
                                  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))
                                  )
                  )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

See by yourself
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center align datatables header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056634/how-to-center-align-datatables-header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

With `#mytable1 .table th` we can access the table header.
With `#mytable1 .table td` we can access the table-cells.

With `text-align: left;` we align the text to the left.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",

  ## CSS-Code ###############
  inlineCSS("
            #mytable1 .table th {
             text-align: left;
            }

            #mytable1 .table td {
             text-align: left;
            }
            "
  ),
   #####################
  sidebarLayout(mainPanel = 
                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      id = 'dataset',
                      tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
                    )
                  ),sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = ggplot2::diamonds[sample(nrow(ggplot2::diamonds), 1000), ]
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds2,
                  extensions = c('Buttons', 
                                 #'Autofill', 
                                 'ColReorder',
                                 'Responsive',
                                 'Scroller'),
                  style = 'bootstrap',
                  class = 'table-bordered stripe table-condensed',
                  filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list( dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                  buttons = list(list(extend = 'csv',
                                                      buttons = c('csv'),
                                                      exportOptions = list(modifiers = list(page = "current"))
                                  )
                                  ),
                                  search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = FALSE),
                                  #autofill = TRUE,
                                  colReorder = TRUE,
                                  deferRender = TRUE,
                                  scrollY = 200,
                                  scroller = TRUE,
                                  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))
                  )
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's great ! Is there a way to extract the css to a file as opposed to have it in the ui ?

Comment: Yes of course, you can write a css file, store it in a `www`-folder and include this `includeCSS("*****.css")` in your ui. Check out this [page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)

Comment: adding it to www did not work (might be theme=) but simply addng it next to the app.R did it !

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-head-center', targets = '_all'))
```